# Table coming out of div when align left used

Tags: html, css

I am working on a case where I have a table which parent is a div. The table has align="left" and immediately the table goes out of the div.

Now that I don't have a control on the table I should be operating on the div to get it working

```css
table, th, td {
border: 1px solid black;
}
#container_div{
background-color : red;
padding:10px;
}
```

```html
<div id = "container_div">
<table align="left">
  <tr>
    <th>Month</th>
    <th>Savings</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>January</td>
    <td>$100</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>February</td>
    <td>$80</td>
  </tr>
</table>
</div>
```

Comment: `align='left'` adds a `float: left` property to the `table` element... thats why you get as above...

Answer (score 0):

Use `overflow:hidden;` on your `container_div`:

```css
table, th, td {
    border: 1px solid black;
}

#container_div {
    overflow: hidden; /* add this line */
    background-color: red;
    padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div id="container_div">
    <table align="left">
      <tr>
        <th>Month</th>
        <th>Savings</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>January</td>
        <td>$100</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>February</td>
        <td>$80</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

Comment: I dont have a control on the table

Answer (score 0):

This is because `text-align:left` sets `float:left`. Try this:

```
#container_div{
    background-color : red;
    padding:10px;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: That will make the div too wide.(100% + 20px). Better would be a standard clearfix solution.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think a pseudo element like table::after will work. Are you able to set a div right after the table like this?

```css
table, th, td {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
#container_div {
  background-color: red;
  padding:10px;
}
.clear { 
  clear: both;
}
```

```html
<div id="container_div">
<table align="left">
  <tr>
    <th>Month</th>
    <th>Savings</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>January</td>
    <td>$100</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>February</td>
    <td>$80</td>
  </tr>
</table>
<div class="clear"> </div>
</div>
```